# Deleting from file in python. OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, file

Trying to delete a line from my file in python, and its throwing me this error. I have a student database, I want to delete a student/line that has the corresponding student id. E.g., `line = 'SanVin22\tSanji\tVinsmoke\tWellington'`. id is the inputted id.

```
def DelStudent(self, data):
        
  self = id

  with open(data, "r+") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
      datum = line.split()
      if datum[0] == id:
        os.remove(line)       
  pass
```

Error is:

```
   os.remove(line)
    OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'SanVin22\tSanji\tVinsmoke\tsanji@gmail.com\tWellington\t'
```

I've tried replacing `os.remove(line)` with `datafile.write(line)`, as all of the tutorials I've seen online, but that ends up deleting every list in the database.

Comment: `os.remove` removes a file by the name you pass to it, not a single line from the file. You're now trying to remove a file with the name `''SanVin22\tSanji\tVinsmoke\tWellington'`, and tabs aren't allowed in filenames, hence incorrect name.

Comment: Oh dang, that explains it, thank you. Do you know what I could substitute it with? I've only seen datafile.write(line) as an option but that keeps deleting everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is to delete the line with the given `id`, then gather up all of the non-matching lines (i.e. those that we want to keep) and then write them back to the original file.

```
def DelStudent(self, data):
    new_lines = []
    with open(data, "r+") as datafile:
        for line in datafile:
            datum = line.split()
            if datum[0] != id:
                new_lines.append(line)
    with open(data, "w") as datafile:
        for line in new_lines:
            datafile.write(line)
```